# How to disable JavaScript in PhantomJS through Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I want to disable JavaScript while scraping using scrapy and selenium.
Moto of doing that is to increase scraping speed. I found the preference for Firefox driver but not PhantomJS.

```
firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", False)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
driver.get('http://www.quora.com/')
```

How can this be done for PhantomJS webdriver?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The WebDriver protocol in PhantomJS is a pure JavaScript implementation that is known as Ghostdriver. It makes heavy use of [`page.evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) to access the DOM and there is really no other way to access the DOM, interact with the page or do anything meaningful with PhantomJS. You shouldn't do this.

If you still want to go through with it, this should work:

```
cap = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS
cap["phantomjs.page.settings.javascriptEnabled"] = False
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=cap)
```

Comment: It looks like you're passing `desired_capabilities` into the driver's constructor. What if you want javascript on for some pages and off for others? How can you set `desired_capabilities` between calls?

Comment: @speedplane Here's a hint: you can change it through [PhantomJS' API of `page.settings.javascriptEnabled`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html). For that, you need to be able to execute scripts in the context of PhantomJS and not in the context of the page (see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32192382/1816580)).

Answer (score 0):

If the site does not require JavaScript, just use scrapy alone. There is no need for selenium. Scrapy is extremely fast for non JavaScript pages.

Comment: I need selenium webdriver for retrieving CSS-style elements. Can you suggest other tools in place of selenium.  I cant get CSS properties by just using scrapy. I dont think i require JavaScript.